# JSOM duplicate folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, jsom

i'm creating folders in sharepoint online using JSOM. And experiencing kinda funny behavior, when folders are created with duplicate with some kind of timestamp as suffix to the filename. Ie. **Foldername(2016-01-26_15-01-21_25125)** when i create **Foldername** folder.

Anyone else experienced this? I know i can use REST as workaround, but i'm curious if it is bug or if i'm doing something wrong.

```
list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("library");

var newFolderInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
newFolderInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder)                      
newFolderInfo.set_leafName('Foldername');
var newFolder = list.addItem(newFolderInfo);
newFolder.set_item('Title', 'display name');
newFolder.update();
//clientContext.load(newFolder);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
```

etc.

Duplicate folder is not created immediately after the one with correct name, but about minute after it.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this was specific case of the environment, someone created workflow that created these same folders.

Unfortunately i can't seem to find a way to delete this question.